# Integral of an integral

Tags: matlab

Why does the error message of this code return: "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.", when I am using ceil for every subscript?

```
A=1:1:100; 
B=1:1:100; 
C=1; 
D=1:1:100; 
E=2; 
F=1:1:100;
G=1:1:100; 
H=0.1:0.1:10; 
fun_1=@(t)integral(@(ti)G(ceil(ti)).*H(ceil(t-ti)),0.1,t-1);
fun_2=@(t)integral(@(ti)G(ceil(ti)).*B(ceil(ti)).*(C.*D(t).^E)./F(t).*...
exp(-integral(@(x)(C.*D(ceil(x)).^E)./F(ceil(x)),ti,5)-K.*(t-ti)),0.1,t-
1,'ArrayValued',true);
I=500;
J=1000; 
K=2;
fun_3=@(t)I*integral(@(ti)min(fun_2(ceil(ti)),J).*exp(-(K+I).*(t-ti)),0.1,t-
1);
t=1:1:5;
figure(1)
fplot(fun_1,t);
figure(2)
fplot(fun_2,t);
figure(3)
fplot(fun_3,t);
```

Comment: This code doesn't initially produce that error, since you haven't even defined `K` before it is used. Please state which line is giving you an error. Also you shouldn't have to spray this many `ceil` calls through your code, some context would help us give better answers.

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you for replying,

you are right, there are lots of ceil, but I use them

Comment: When you edit your question (click "edit" beneath the tags) you can click the option to insert an image.

Comment: However I don't have 10 reputation

Comment: You can edit your question with 1 rep...

Comment: After moving the definition of I, J, and K above the fun_# lines, I get this error when `fplot(fun_2,t)` is called.   I'm not sure if this is related but are you calling `fplot` correctly.  It is supposed to be called as `fplot(fun,limits)` where `limits` are [xmin xmax] or [xmin xmax ymin ymax].  Basically the range to plot the `fun` over.  But you are passing it `t` which is `1:5` ...?

Comment: @Aero Engy well this worked for fun_1.. changed it anyway and it still doesn’t work... still have "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals."

Comment: https://instagram.com/p/BaZZKKnh1X-/ the picture should be available here

Comment: I am going to write this as an answer but I do not think fplot is doing what you think it is doing...I am going to explain more as an answer because this comment box is too small... standby

Comment: @Wolfie did you get to check the equation I uploaded? [link](https://www.instagram.com/p/BaZZgFbBwdt/?taken-by=alfredo.but)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fplot [see documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html) Called as `fplot(f,xinterval)` evaluates your function handle `f` over the interval `xinterval`.  IT will evaluate `f` at automatically determined steps along that given interval.

From the docs:

> xinterval — Interval for x [–5 5] (default) | two-element vector of
>   form [xmin xmax]

You seem to be trying to specify exactly where you want your functions evaluated

```
t=1:1:5;
...
fplot(fun_1,t);
```

But it doesn't work that way.  What is happening is that `fplot` is evaluating the function from 1 to 2 (the first 2 elements of `t`).  So for example it might feed values of t = 1, 1.05, 1.1,... ,2 into your fun_# functions.

You can tell this because you first function which does work actually plots over the x-range of 1 to 2.

The reason you are getting a subscript indices error is because in fun_2 you have this `...(C.*D(t).^E)./F(t).*...`  Since fplot is feeding in values for t which are spaced between 1 and 2 (ex. 1.1) that is not a valid index.

If you really just want the values of your functions at `t = 1:1:5`  The you probably do not want to use fplot and just want evaluate the functions at those times and plot it.

```
y = feval(fun_1,t);
plot(t,y)
```

**EDIT**: The above code doesn't work

You will need to do something like the code below.  This is because the 2nd & 3rd trems to [the intergral function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) need to be scalar (1x1).  If you feed them an array for t then they crash.  So evaluate at each `t` not all at once.

```
figure(1)
y_1 = arrayfun(fun_1,t);
plot(t,y_1);
figure(2)
y_2 = arrayfun(fun_2,t);
plot(t,y_2);
figure(3)
y_3 = arrayfun(fun_3,t);
plot(t,y_3);
```

Note: the Third function still errors ... and I'm not 100% sure why.  I didn't really look at it.

Comment: Thank you, yes I was was too focused on the other errors and did not check this one, which seems obvious afterwards ... but there still is the problem with integral ... Indeed, the message is now  « Error using integral (line 85) A and B must be floating-point scalars. »  I will look further and tell you if I find or not

Comment: Now the code looks like this :
`...
fun_1=@(t)integral(@(ti)G(ceil(ti)).*H(ceil(t-ti)),0,t-1);
fun_2=@(t)integral(@(ti)G(ceil(ti)).*B(ceil(ti)).*(C.*D(t).^E)./F(t).*...
    exp(-integral(@(x)(C.*D(ceil(x)).^E)./F(ceil(x)),ti,5)-K.*(t-ti)),0,t-1);
fun_3=@(t)I*integral(@(ti)min(fun_2(ceil(ti)),J).*exp(-(K+I).*(t-ti)),0.1,t-1);
t=2:1:5; figure(1) y = feval(fun_1,t); plot(t,y) figure(2) y = feval(fun_2,t); plot(t,y) figure(3) y = feval(fun_3,t); plot(t,y)`

Comment: I am going to edit the end of my answer which gets you closer.  I am still getting a crash on the third function now...

Comment: Edit added to my answer. Also note I can not check the content of your equations or there correctness.  Instagram is blocked at my office so I can't see what the equations looks like ... or tell if you converted that over to code correctly.

Comment: Thank you already for the help ! ooh they block instagram ... maybe not a bad idea ^^

Best wishes,
Alfredo B.

Comment: Welll you didn't totally solve the problem, I still have this floating point error using integral.

Comment: And it is very slow, I think there must be another way, maybe with symbolic functions..